# (TXT File) Java GUI Login

Tags: java, swing, text-files

I want to login from a text file called "members.txt" which using 2nd (username) and third (password) line with "/" delimiter. But when I run it, it seems they recognize all of text file's account in sequence. Please help. Here's my code.

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            String s;
            String bypassid = "guest";
            String bypasspw = "guest";
            String[] array;
            boolean isLogin= false; // 포기
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("members.txt"));;
            while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
                array=s.split("/");
                if(txtID.getText().equals(array[1])&&txtPass.getText().equals(array[2])){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "로그인 되셨습니다");
                    break;
                } else if(array.length != 0 && bypassid.equals(txtID.getText())&&bypasspw.equals(txtPass.getText())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "로그인 되셨습니다");
                    break;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "계정 정보를 다시 확인해주세요.");
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e10) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e10.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The code seems to go through all username/password and check with input and if both username and password match, loop will break. Otherwise it will print "계정 정보를 다시 확인해주세요." for every line in file.
What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: You are using `array[1]` and `array[2]`. Unless I'm missing something arrays start at 0, so your first element is `array[0] ` and the second would be `array[1]`. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you sign up with an account of User 1, User 2, User 3, and then try to log in as User 3,

​
Once the login button is pressed,
In the data value for user 1, the alarm "Login failed.

In the data value for user 2, the alarm "Login failed" appears.

The data value for user 3 indicates successful login.

I would like to post a notification window of successful login by recognizing only the correct user in the user list.

Comment: This whole process occurs with a single press of the login button.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65488679/418556) with seemingly equivalent code. OP: Don't start new questions about the same problem, instead [edit] this question.

Comment: Let's see.  You don't show us a sample from your members.txt file.  You don't explain in English what your messages are in your message dialogs.  You don't provide a [mre] displaying your problem clearly so we can grab the code, put it in our IDE, and tinker with it until it works.  When you're ready to edit this question and help us, then maybe someone will help you.

Comment: Do not hardcode any position to be accessed from an array without checking its size first, and the value that could be stored inside...no matter how sure you're

Comment: Thank you to everyone about add to comment to my a deficient Problem.

The problem was solved thanks to the yours.

Comment: Happy new years everyone! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are reading every line and if user/password doesn't match, you print error message in else {} block. You can just set boolean variable isLogin once and see if isLogin is false, print error message once outside loop. Below is the code snippet for that. Replace your actionPerformed method with code below

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String s;
                String bypassid = "guest";
                String bypasspw = "guest";
                String[] array;
                boolean isLogin= false; // 포기
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("members.txt"));
                while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    array=s.split("/");
                    if(txtID.getText().equals(array[1])&&txtPass.getText().equals(array[2])){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "로그인 되셨습니다");
                        isLogin = true;
                        break;
                    } else if(array.length != 0 && bypassid.equals(txtID.getText())&&bypasspw.equals(txtPass.getText())){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "로그인 되셨습니다");
                        isLogin = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!isLogin) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "계정 정보를 다시 확인해주세요.");
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e10) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e10.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Just be careful about what @David Kroukamp mentioned in comment

Comment: thank you so much...
Your advice was a big help.I was able to solve the problem 100%.